# Could not find member <method name> in Swift (multiple instances)

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

I am trying to build my Xcode project however, I keep getting "Could not find member " build errors in three different instances from the code below. Please help.

Instances:

1. Could not find member 'dataSource' `self.pageViewController.dataSource = self`

2&3. Could not find member 'Forward' `self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var pageViewController: UIViewController!
    var pageTitles: NSArray!
    var pageImages: NSArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pageTitles = NSArray(objects: "Welcome", "Hello")
        self.pageImages = NSArray(objects: "page1", "page2")

        self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

        var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
        var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 60 )

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func restartAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
        var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController

    {

        if ((self.pageTitles.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageTitles.count))
        {
            return ContentViewController()
        }

        var vc: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController

        vc.imageFile = self.pageImages[index] as! String
        vc.titleText = self.pageTitles[index] as! String
        vc.pageIndex = index

        return vc 


    }

    //MARK: - Page View Controller Data Source

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
        var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

        if (index == 0 || index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil
        }

        index--
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
        var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

        if (index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil
        }

        index++
        if (index == self.pageTitles.count)
        {
            return nil
        }

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return self.pageTitles.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change this:

```
var pageViewController: UIViewController!
```

to this:

```
var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
```

Comment: Thank you for that Mike! Ive just tried that and it seemed to work then flagged up another bug: ('NSArray' is not implicitly convertible to '[AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?)

Comment: If that error is occurring on call to setViewControllers, then instead of var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC), try var viewControllers = [startVC].